How to detect specific activity is being registered for registerForActivityResult to create if statements for different activities
I am creating a project that uses Bluetooth functions. Right now I enable the Bluetooth by sending Intent BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE to my activityResultLauncher which is my registerForActivityResult.
Here is my entire code done on Android Studio in Java. The focus is on the Turn on bluetooth function set on my button labeled 'b1'
package com.example.detech2;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected static final String TAG = "MYTAG";
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher = null;
    int BLUETOOTH_CONNECT = 2;
    int BLUETOOTH_SCAN = 3;
    int ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 4;
    int ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 5;



    public ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mDeviceList = new ArrayList<>();

    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });

        //Permission initial check on first startup
        //Location permission check
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        }
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT}, BLUETOOTH_CONNECT);
        }

        Button b1 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button b3 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Button b4 = findViewById(R.id.button5);

        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


        mDeviceList = new ArrayList<>();


        assert bluetoothAdapter != null;
        if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Log.d(TAG, " Btooth button changed");
            b1.setText(R.string.bluetooth_enabled);
            b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDBDBD"));
        }

        //Turn on bluetooth
        b1.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            //Check if bluetooth is enabled

            if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) { //if not enabled

                //Check Bluetooth permission before requesting to enable Bluetooth
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT}, BLUETOOTH_CONNECT);
                    return;
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT}, BLUETOOTH_CONNECT);
                }
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                activityResultLauncher.launch(enableBtIntent); //Ask to enable Bluetooth
            }
            //Bluetooth is enabled
            else if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Log.d("mytag", " Btooth enabled");
                b1.setText(R.string.bluetooth_enabled);
                b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDBDBD"));
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Bluetooth already enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {
            if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            }
        });


        //show list of bluetooth devices
        // end of onClick
        b3.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN}, BLUETOOTH_SCAN);
                        return;
                    } else {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN}, BLUETOOTH_SCAN);
                    }
                    return;
                }
                if (!bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
                    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
                    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
                    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
                    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
                    bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
                } else if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                    Log.d("MyTag", "cancel discovery");
                    bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                }

            }


        }); // end of b3

        b4.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
            activityResultLauncher.launch(discoverableIntent);
        });


    } //end of oncreate


    // Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND.
    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            Button b3 = findViewById(R.id.button4);

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Discovery has found a device. Get the BluetoothDevice
                // object and its info from the Intent.
                Log.d("Mytag", "Reached");
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                //Check permission
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT}, BLUETOOTH_CONNECT);
                } else {
                    assert device != null;
                    mDeviceList.add(device);
                    ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDeviceList);
                    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    listView.deferNotifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
                listView.clearChoices();
                mDeviceList.clear();
                b3.setText(R.string.searching_for_devices);
                b3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDBDBD"));
                Log.d("mytag", "Discovery started");
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                b3.setText(R.string.show_list);
                b3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5734bf"));
                Log.d("mytag", "Discovery done");

                //discovery finishes, dismiss progress dialog
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE.equals(action)) {
                Log.d("mytag", "mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverability Enabled.");
            }
            listView.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, id) -> {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN}, BLUETOOTH_SCAN);
                    return;
                }
                bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                String deviceName = mDeviceList.get(position).getName();
                String deviceAddress = mDeviceList.get(position).getAddress();
                Log.d("mytag", "Trying to pair with " + deviceName);
                mDeviceList.get(position).createBond();
            });


        }
    };




    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Don't forget to unregister the ACTION_FOUND receiver.
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }



} //End of mainActivity



I tried to get the intent when I launched enableBTIntent but the values were null in the activity registry. Question is, how do I take specific activities (one for enabling bluetooth and one for enabling bluetooth discovery since i have register both of them) so that I can set specific if statements (changing button to gray to show bluetooth is enabled and changing another button to other colours when discoverability is turned on). Any methods/alternatives or suggestions is greatly appreaciated

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
